# Changing a MySQL stored procedure to get the Titles instead of the IDs

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I have a MySQL database that includes a table of components that are hierarchical (each non-top level component has a parent component)

It includes an SQL function `GetParents(ComponentID)`, which returns a comma separated list of parent `ComponentID`s, starting with the direct parent and going up. This is working correctly and as intended.

I copied that function to `GetPath(ComponentID` and tried to get it to return the `Title` instead of the ID, as well as changing the order so it starts with the top parent and going down, but got stuck. I managed to change the order, and the `,` to a `->`, as well as changing the top level ID (0) to `(Top Level)` (except for top level assets!), but couldn't figure out how to get the titles instead of the IDs.

Unfortunately sqlfiddle doesn't like `DELIMITER` (any alternatives?) but below is the code, including table schema and inserts that satisfy the following examples:

`SELECT GetParents(11);` should return `4,1,0`. This is working correctly right now and I only include it for completeness.

`SELECT GetPath(11);` currently returns `(Top Level) -> 1 -> 4`, but I want to make it return `(Top Level) -> Cars -> Car 1`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Components`;
CREATE TABLE `Components` (
  `ComponentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentComponentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Components`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ComponentID`);

ALTER TABLE `Components`
  MODIFY `ComponentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Components (ParentComponentID, Title) VALUES 
(0, 'Cars'),(0,'Trucks'),(0,'Boats');

INSERT INTO Components (ParentComponentID, Title) VALUES 
(1, 'Car 1'),(1,'Car 2'),(1,'Car 3'),(2,'Truck 1'),(3,'Boat 3');

INSERT INTO Components (ParentComponentID, Title) VALUES 
(4, 'Wheel 1'),(4,'Wheel 2'),(4,'Wheel 3'),(4,'Wheel 4');

INSERT INTO Components (ParentComponentID, Title) VALUES 
(5, 'Wheel 1'),(5,'Wheel 2'),(5,'Wheel 3'),(5,'Wheel 4');

-- Functions

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetParents` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetParents` (GivenID  VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children,front_id VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE queue_length,pos INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;

    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = queue;
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ParentComponentID) qc
        FROM Components WHERE ComponentID = front_id AND ParentComponentID!=ComponentID) A;

        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN rv;
END $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetPath` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetPath` (GivenID  VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children,front_id VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE queue_length,pos INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;

    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = queue;
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ParentComponentID) qc
        FROM Components WHERE ComponentID = front_id AND ParentComponentID!=ComponentID) A;

        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                IF (queue_children = 0) THEN
                    SET rv = CONCAT('(Top Level) -> ',rv);
                ELSE
                    SET rv = CONCAT(queue_children,' -> ',rv);
                END IF;
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN rv;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The function will be called in the context of `SELECT getPath(ComponentID) FROM Components`, a table which could have many entries, so it would be good to have an efficient algorithm!

Thanks!